# java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip entry source

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("/file/path/report.xlsx"); 
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file); --!ERROR LINE!--
```

I get an error in the 2nd line. I looked at different online resources such as this:

[Error reading Excel .XLSX with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145323/error-reading-excel-xlsx-with-apache-poi)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip entry source
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:106)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:342)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:285)
    at test.test.main(test.java:48)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Zip bomb detected! The file would exceed the max. ratio of compressed file size to the size of the expanded data. This may indicate that the file is used to inflate memory usage and thus could pose a security risk. You can adjust this limit via ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio() if you need to work with files which exceed this limit. Counter: 1483367, cis.counter: 14796, ratio: 0.009974605070761314Limits: MIN_INFLATE_RATIO: 0.01
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream.advance(ZipSecureFile.java:257)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream.read(ZipSecureFile.java:214)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource$FakeZipEntry.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:132)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:99)
    ... 4 more
```

I added         **ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(0.009);**

```
   FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("/file/path/report.xlsx"); 
   ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(0.009);
   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

***It worked fine for a while, then it started throwing the same error***

Any Help or Guidance is appreciated.

Comment: If you trust the file, what happens if you put a much later ratio in?

Comment: @Gagravarr I trust the file, is there a way to override the check? like, ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(-1.0d); ?

Comment: IIRC you can set a ratio of `0` to disable the check, but only do that if you trust the file!

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks. What does `(-1.0d)` mean? and how is it different from passing `(0)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding the below line did the trick for me.

```
ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(-1.0d);
```

The code looks like:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("/file/path/report.xlsx"); 
ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(-1.0d);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```