# IoException zip entry size too large

Tags: apache-poi, openxml

I'm using xmlslideshow and passing inputstream to the constructor of xmlslideshow but greeting a exception zip entry size too large . I'm using poi 3.9

Comment: poi 3.9 was released nine years ago - can you use POI 5.1.0 - the latest release?

Comment: Check this post: [java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip entry source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796874/java-io-ioexception-failed-to-read-zip-entry-source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue came because earlier we used to create ear file due to requirements Changes we started creating war files and deploy war on Apache server . So ppt template was getting corrupted . So instead of keeping ppt template in resources folder just keep it on you Apache server and read it from there .it's a work around. But as a developer you cannot do anything regarding setup and check why ppt template was getting courrupted when war was getting created